What do I miss to see the texture?
It has been a while since I played with blender and must have lost basic understanding of it.
This must be something very simple or I am just missing something. I am trying to add material/texture to an object. However, it takes a color, but not the texture/image, nor any of the maps for some reason. I downloaded map from polyhaven and preview on the right hand side shows correct texture. But material applied on the object does not take the texture..
I have tried to change engine from Eevee to Cycles, but texture is still not there. Tried to render an image but it still just stays gray, without the texture.


Please share your Blend file having first packed the texture files via Blender's File > External Data > Pack Resources menu.  You can then share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Thank you John for taking your time and detailed instructions how to do it. I have uploaded .blend file with packed textures.

No problem. As you'll see you have an answer from josh. The only thing I'd add is that you can clean up some of your objects by selecting All in Edit mode and then using the Mesh > Clean up > Limited Dissolve menu. That will get rid of a lot of the unnecessary extra edges that Sketchup seems to add to triangulate the faces and will leave a much tidier UV map when you UV unwrap the object.

Your object is missing an appropriate UV Map.
To solve go to Edit mode, select all, press U > Smart UV project.


Thanks, it solved the issue. I tried to Unwrap it with vertex option and did not get anything good initially. But with faces option and smart UV project I got it!
